# Weird properties for every UI element in Storyboard Xcode

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xib

In all my storyboards and XIB attribute inspector, there are weird properties "View" in every UI (UIView, UIButton, UILabel, etc) I created.

- My Top
- My Leading

until

- Clear Float

But it doesn't appear in new project I created. May I know what is the function of these properties, and how to get rid of this if they are unnecessary ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your project you have `extension UIView` with those custom properties.

It will probably look something like this:

```
@IBDesignable
extension UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable
    public var myTop: CGFloat
    {
        set (myTop) {
            // some code here...
        }
        get {
            return self.myTop
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    public var myLeading: CGFloat
    {
        set (myBottom) {
            // some code here...
        }
        get {
            return self.myLeading
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    public var myBottom: CGFloat
    {
        set (myBottom) {
            // some code here...
        }
        get {
            return self.myBottom
        }
    }
    
    // and so on....

}
```

Do a text search in your project for `extension UIView` and you should find it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Will be digging more soon.